# Normalise 2D Numpy Array: Zero Mean Unit Variance

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D Numpy array, in which I want to normalise each column to zero mean and unit variance. Since I'm primarily used to C++, the method in which I'm doing is to use loops to iterate over elements in a column and do the necessary operations, followed by repeating this for all columns. I wanted to know about a pythonic way to do so.

Let `class_input_data` be my 2D array. I can get the column mean as:

```
column_mean = numpy.sum(class_input_data, axis = 0)/class_input_data.shape[0]
```

I then subtract the mean from all columns by:

```
class_input_data = class_input_data - column_mean
```

By now, the data should be zero mean. However, the value of:

```
numpy.sum(class_input_data, axis = 0)
```

isn't equal to 0, implying that I have done something wrong in my normalisation. By isn't equal to 0, I don't mean very small numbers which can be attributed to floating point inaccuracies.

Comment: Subtract the mean from each column, and divide by the variance.

Comment: Why not just use numpy.mean ?

Comment: @nitbix : Thanks for your comment, but I have no idea why I didn't use it at that time. Maybe there were some issues or something. However, this being a few months old, I don't remember the other details. Out of curiosity, how did you stumble across this question now?

Comment: I was just googling some random things on normalisation to unit variance and landed here! I wonder if maybe that caused your mean to be off. Who knows.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Something like:

```
import numpy as np

eg_array = 5 + (np.random.randn(10, 10) * 2)
normed = (eg_array - eg_array.mean(axis=0)) / eg_array.std(axis=0)

normed.mean(axis=0)
Out[14]: 
array([  1.16573418e-16,  -7.77156117e-17,  -1.77635684e-16,
         9.43689571e-17,  -2.22044605e-17,  -6.09234885e-16,
        -2.22044605e-16,  -4.44089210e-17,  -7.10542736e-16,
         4.21884749e-16])

normed.std(axis=0)
Out[15]: array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
```

Comment: Could you point out the mistake in the code I have provided in the question? I feel it is something silly, but can't figure it out

Comment: The code basically looks right. If your data are skewed (non-symmetric around the mean) and your standard deviation/variance is large I guess that would lead to sums that are far from 0?

Comment: I used this code in my data. My data has 42 features. The first few features are two three order of magnitudes larger than the other. The mean vector observed has the first few entries as non zero, while the last ones tend to zero. Any particular explanation for this? I don't think the variance is so large so as to create any issues