# How do I better process my data and set parameters for my Neural Network?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network

When I run my NN the only way to get any training to occur is if I divide X by 1000. The network also needs to be trained under 70000 times with a 0.03 training rate and if those values are larger the NN gets worse. I think this is a due to bad processing of data and maybe the lack of having biases, but I don't really know. 
[Code on Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11RXhjtgvYutjMJ6JUvzNG8o8JOXx3C9i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: all of the problems you mentioned and more.

- Scaling is essential, [typically to 0 mean and a variance of 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31152967/normalise-2d-numpy-array-zero-mean-unit-variance). Otherwise, you will quickly saturate the hidden units, their gradients will be near zero and (almost) no learning will be possible.
- Bias is mandatory for such ANN. It's like an offset for fitting linear function. If you drop it, getting good fit will be very difficult.
- You seem to be checking accuracy on your training data.
- You have very few training samples.
- Sigmoid is proven to be poor choice. Use ReLU and check e.g. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126238/what-are-the-advantages-of-relu-over-sigmoid-function-in-deep-neural-networks) for explanation.

Also, I'd recommend spending some time on learning Python before going into this. For starter, avoid using `global`, it can get you unforeseen behaviour if you're not careful.

Comment: Thanks! Right after seeing this I implemented the bias unit and the accuracy went up to 92%. I am still working on fixing the other items on the list, however.